# how to use intent caller on button click properly?

Tags: android, class, android-intent

actually I am bit confused on some thing which is working in one scenario very well but  in other scenario that is not working fine so I am here to explain my problem to identify the wrong move made by me, if any on will identify the problem please mention it. thank you.

working fine:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.distance_demo_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListViewClass.class);
        intent.putExtra(ListViewClass.EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY, Distance.class.getName());
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
```

NOt working fine:

```
scan = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan);
    scan.setOnClickListener(startListener);


    }

 //Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
  private OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListViewClass.class);


           intent.putExtra(ListViewClass.EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY, Distance.class.getName());
            startActivity(intent);
       }
}
```

now the problem is in this line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListViewClass.class);
```

when I use this line in this scenario it shows me error on this line:

`Error: 'The constructor Intent(MainActivity, Class<ListViewClass>) is undefined'` please mention my problem if you are well aware of it.

Comment: Could you please show the entire class to see if dependencies cause the error?

Comment: What class is the second chunk of code in?

Comment: @steve its better to implement onclicklistener in your activity class instead of make many instances on on click listener.then acording to view just  use switch case.

Answer (score 0):

use a global context variable glaboaly and use it.

```
Context myContext;
 @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myContext = MyActivity.this;
}
```

and use `myContext` insted of `MainActivity.this`.
Im not sure whether it solve the problem, just try it out

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from RoomView to Context

this error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

When your calling  `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListViewClass.class);` inside MainActivity class. It will work fine. But when your not in Context of `MainActivity class`. i.e move to other class. This error will occur.

If you want to rectify, You can follow @jithu method. Otherwise store the context in Application class. And use it in anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are overriding the method *onClick()*.
If you override the method it's like you are declaring the function in your activity class.
This is the reason that you can call *MainActivity.this*

In the second case you are implementing the abstract method *onClick()*. You can't call *MainActivity.this* because your "*MainActivity.this*" is referencing to the current context and this isn't accessible from *OnClickListener.class*.

Comment: This refers to current class. in this case it is onClickListener. MainActivity.this refers to whole MainActivity class. His code is correct. But he is using intent out of Mainactivity class. That is the issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Ramesh_D, I correct my answer that it was a little bit confusing. Thanks.